# Unknown option "testTimeout" with value was found for jest test run in vscode output

Tags: javascript, jestjs

Unable to configure jest properly.

Running `jest --testTimeout 10000 --verbose` works but configuring using file does not.

##### **`jest.config.js`**

```js
module.exports = {
  verbose: true,
  testTimeout: 10000,
};
```

When I press run for the test, my tests fail due to timeout and I get the following logs in vscode output panel

```
● Validation Warning:

  Unknown option "verbose" with value true was found.
  This is probably a typing mistake. Fixing it will remove this message.

  Configuration Documentation:
  https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration

● Validation Warning:

  Unknown option "testTimeout" with value 10000 was found.
  This is probably a typing mistake. Fixing it will remove this message.

  Configuration Documentation:
  https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration
```

I found [a similar bug in github](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/10522) but no activity. Can someone help?

Comment: On careful observation, I think this is not an issue just a distraction. I had some other issue in code, but seeing these logs about testTimeout, it seemed that might be the cause. `npx jest --debug` shows the correct testTimeout being set despite these messages.